# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I checked similar questions in this error but none is useful here is my code :

```
def update(up_margin=None, margin=None, time=None, history=None, clean_type=None):
    update_column = ''

    columns = {'up_margin': up_margin, 'margin': margin, 'time': time, 'history': history, 'type': clean_type}
    for key, value in columns:
        if value is not None:
            if update_column != '':
                update_column += ','
            update_column += '{}={}'.format(key, value)
    print(update_column)

update(up_margin=100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def update(up_margin=None, margin=None, time=None, history=None, clean_type=None):
    update_column = ''

    columns = {'up_margin': up_margin, 'margin': margin, 'time': time, 'history': history, 'type': clean_type}
    for key, value in columns.items():
        if value is not None:
            if update_column != '':
                update_column += ','
            update_column += '{}={}'.format(key, value)
    print(update_column)

update(up_margin=100)
```

When iterating over a map, use .items()

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate over the `items()` of your dictionary.

Change your for loop to

```py
for key, value in columns.items():
```